# Rename a row with X unknown characters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have the following dataframe:

| ID | other |
| --- | --- |
| 219218 | 34 |
| 823#32 | 47 |
| unknown | 42 |
| 8#3#32 | 32 |
| 1#3#5# | 97 |
| 6#3### | 27 |

I want to obtain the following result:

| ID | other |
| --- | --- |
| 219218 | 34 |
| 823#32 | 47 |
| unknown | 42 |
| 8#3#32 | 32 |
| unknown | 97 |
| unknown | 27 |

I am using the following code which works.

```
for i in range(len(df)):
  ident = testing.loc[i, 'ID']
  if ident.count('#') > 2:
    df.loc[i, 'ID'] = 'unknown'
```

Is there a way to make it more optimal, bearing in mind that I am going to apply the code to a dataframe of more than 60,000 rows?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an efficient solution, use vectorial methods and assign with `loc`:

```
df.loc[df['ID'].str.count('#').gt(2), 'ID'] = 'unknown'
```

output:

```
        ID  other
0   219218     34
1   823#32     47
2  unknown     42
3   8#3#32     32
4  unknown     97
5  unknown     27
```